# Error compiling gcc 4.6.2 under ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gcc, ubuntu

I have one problem compiling gcc 4.6.2 under ubuntu 11.10. 
The error is quite popular i.e. /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
I tried to LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu where crti.o could be found by the linker but then the configuration complains that LIBRARY_PATH should not contain the path of the current directory when building gcc

```
checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... contains current directory
configure: error: 
*** LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't contain the current directory when
*** building gcc. Please change the environment variable
*** and run configure again.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage2-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abdul/cc02/gcc-4.6.2/src-infra/obj-gcc'
make[1]: *** [stage2-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abdul/cc02/gcc-4.6.2/src-infra/obj-gcc'
```

I have also tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH but no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `env | grep '^LIBRARY_PATH='` report?

Comment: IBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apparently, your `LIBRARY_PATH` ends in a colon:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:
#  -----------------------^
```

Get rid of that:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: Hint: If that stupid colon occured, [don't forget to check `C_INCLUDE_PATH`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13874779/321973) while you're at it...

Comment: On my system the colon was in the beginning, so check that too

Comment: It seems a double colon in the middle of the path can also upset it (and is hard to spot!)

Answer (score 4):

Combining the answers of @hmb, @FredFoo, and avoiding assumptions about users' systems:

It seems your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ends with a colon, which GCC doesn't approve of. You should also ensure `C_INCLUDE_PATH` doesn't end with a colon to avoid related issues. Here's how to do it:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$(echo $LIBRARY_PATH | sed 's/:$//; s/^://;')
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH | sed 's/:$//; s/^://;')
```

then re-configure the build (with `configure -v`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69365/cant-build-gcc-anymore-since-upgrade-to-11-10).

Especially in the following comment:

> And, if you don't like patching your sources, and setting flags aren't working for you, just soft-link crt*.o into the /usr/lib dirctory (you'll find them in either /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu). – ams Nov 15 '11 at 14:55

Answer (score 0):

Following command solved problem

**unset LIBRARY_PATH; ./configure -v**