# GCC compilation yields "real.h:53: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' undeclared here (not in a function)"

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm, gcc4.7

I'm trying to compile GCC 4.7.2 on a [Buffalo LinkStation Pro Duo](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/en/linkstatio-pro-duo.html) (after [unlocking](http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/Open_Stock_Firmware_LS-VL) it) which runs Linux 2.6.31.8 armv5tel.

Unfortunately, `make` throws quite some errors, starting with

```
gcc -c  -DIN_GCC_FRONTEND -g -fkeep-inline-functions -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-formIn file included from ../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/tree.h:32,
                 from ../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/c-lang.c:27:
../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/real.h:53: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' undeclared here (not in a function)
In file included from ../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/tree.h:32,
                 from ../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/c-lang.c:27:
../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/real.h:87:5: error: division by zero in #if
../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/real.h:87:5: error: division by zero in #if
../../gcc-4.7.2/gcc/real.h:90:6: error: division by zero in #if
```

Line 53 of `real.h` reads `unsigned long sig[SIGSZ];`, where `SIGSZ` is defined at line 40 as
`#define SIGSZ (SIGNIFICAND_BITS / HOST_BITS_PER_LONG)`
while line 87 is `#if REAL_WIDTH == 1` with `REAL_WIDTH` defined starting at line 72 as
`#define REAL_WIDTH \

  (REAL_VALUE_TYPE_SIZE/HOST_BITS_PER_WIDE_INT \

   + (REAL_VALUE_TYPE_SIZE%HOST_BITS_PER_WIDE_INT ? 1 : 0)) /* round up */`

This seems to boil down to the `HOST_BITS_PER_*` being zero. Do I have to define these manually with some `configure` parameter or how can this issue be resolved?

---

**update**

`config.log` contains the following errors:

```
conftest.c:10:19: error: ppl_c.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:16: error: 'choke' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
conftest.c:16: error: for each function it appears in.)
conftest.c:16: error: expected ';' before 'me'
configure:5708: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include "ppl_c.h"
| int
| main ()
| {
|.
|     #if PPL_VERSION_MAJOR != 0 || PPL_VERSION_MINOR < 11
|     choke me
|     #endif
|.
|   ;
|   r
```

Following [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gnu.gcc.help/72AMJrsw-IU) I seem to have forgotten to install [ppl](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/Download/), which I'll try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIZEOF_LONG` should be `#define`d by `configure` in the file `auto-host.h`. Your `auto-host.h` should contain something like:

```
/* The size of `long', as computed by sizeof. */
#ifndef USED_FOR_TARGET
#define SIZEOF_LONG 8
#endif
```

If the above is not present (and it looks like in your case it's indeed so), check `config.log` for errors. Search for errors around the string `checking size of long`.

Comment: That entry is there, although it's `#define SIZEOF_LONG 4` here. There are other errors in config.log though, I appended them to my question

Comment: I accept your answer since checking `config.log` pointed me to the lack of `ppl`. The actual solution did [involve some more trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13874779/321973) though - if it's the solution, the compilation is still running...

Answer (score 1):

- Thanks to [chill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13861305/321973) I checked `config.log` to discover
  `conftest.c:10:19: error: ppl_c.h: No such file or directory`
  (which, curiously, did not prevent `configure` from creating a Makefile and returning a success error code). The first google hit on that was [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gnu.gcc.help/72AMJrsw-IU), showing I didn't provide the [ppl dependency](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/Download/).
- The ppl-1.0 compilation greeted me with
  `checked_float.inlines.hh:1012: error: 'frexpl' was not declared in this scope`
  which led me to [this post](http://www.cs.unipr.it/pipermail/ppl-devel/2012-September/018538.html) suggesting I'd use [the 1.1 snapshot](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/download/ftp/snapshots/) instead, which worked
- Now, gcc's `make` offered me another "helpful" error:
  `gcc/../libcpp/include/line-map.h:66: error: 'CHAR_BIT'`
  which [turned out](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-11/msg00203.html) to be due to `C_INCLUDE_PATH` [ending with a colon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577424/321973) (I already experienced the `checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... contains current directory` error mentioned in that post, but didn't think about checking other variables for that as well)

Compilation is still running, so far no more errors...