# Why does `configure` not fail while `config.log` contains errors?

Tags: makefile, configure, automake

In [my attempt to compile GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13874779/321973) I noticed that while `./configure` doesn't yield error messages and returns an error code of 0, there are still errors logged in `config.log`, which do later on cause `make` to fail. So, why doesn't `configure` fail already? Or does `make` modify `config.log` later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config.log` contains the output of all `configure` probes.  Some of them are expected to fail.  For example, frequently Autoconf probes for several different possible alternative implementations of particular functionality, and some of them are expected to fail depending on the characteristics of your system.

It's therefore up to the author of the Autoconf `configure.ac` script to explicitly fail the configure step if the results are not viable.  Some people do this when writing their `configure.ac` and some don't.  Sometimes it can be quite hard to know at configure time whether a particular set of findings are viable.  There's also a reasonable argument that it's easier to diagnose problems during the build, later on, than to issue an error message from `configure` and make people search through `config.log` for the details.  That's particularly the case if the problems are relatively obscure.

The short answer is that `configure` didn't fail because the people who wrote the configure script you're running didn't program it to fail for the specific errors that you're seeing, for one reason or another.